# View in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in need of getting data from multiple select queries. So I thought of creating two views and to inner join them to get my data.

My questions is: which option is better

1. creating a view,
2. creating temporary table

Comment: If a join satisfies the query you want to run, why do you need a view *or* a temporary table? How do you define "better"?

Comment: @Aaron..the problem is when i use a single join query i won't get the result because the conditions are different for the select query. so i have to select the  data in two ways...

Comment: Then please provide more details. How are you going to "inner join the two joins" as you stated in your question? Can you show some sample data and desired results, so we have some clue what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Using two VIEWs in your SELECT statement will always be better because it can combine both of the views query plans into a **single optimised query**. Very neat solution which is also fast.

BTW. Using an in-memory temp table > 100 rows generally poor performance because the query plan optimiser assumes there is only 1 row in the temp table.

Comment: When you say "in-memory temp table" are you referring to a table variable?

Comment: @Simon Hughes..thank you Simon..its a great information to me..(by temp table i mean #tables. i think u also mean it).

Comment: i also want to know what you mean by 'in-memory temp table'?.

Comment: I don't know if I would agree that joining two views will be faster than a single join between the same tables. Can you show an example?

Comment: There are table variables and there are temp tables. [Comparing Table Variables with Temporary Tables](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Temporary+Tables/66720/). Both may be stored in memory or on disk.

Comment: @JNK I'm talking about about both temp tables in a variable, and #tables. The query plan will assume only 1 row in the temp table and therefore is generally a poor performer. If you want to a temp table with 100+ rows and be fast, you have to add an index to the #temp table. (you can't add an index to a variable table).

Comment: "Because table variables have a limited scope and are not part of the persistent database, transaction rollbacks do not affect them". You have to understand the meanings of this phrase: table variables are not influenced by transactions

Comment: Full information on this topic can be found here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Temporary+Tables/66720/